# Using a Boolean in a Constructor Class - p5.js

Tags: p5.js

still new to p5.js.  As a simple function in p5.js, I'm trying to make it so that when I click in a rectangle that it changes colour as well as that change in colour acknowledges a change in state.  I have successfully done this in Processing easy enough but am having a hard time converting it into p5.js. I find that I can't declare an array in the *constructor* within the Class.  Any support is appreciated!  I have commented out some things that are not relevant right now.  Here is the code in OpenProcessing:

```
oppr.org/s/hM1EW3ch
```

`

```
let sample = [];
let bassDrum = [];
let snareDrum = [];
let hiHat = [];

let bassRow = [16];
let snareRow = [16];
let hiHatRow = [16];

let col = 0;

// function preload() {
//  sample[0] = loadSound('./BD.wav');
//  sample[1] = loadSound('./SD.wav');
//  sample[2] = loadSound('./CHH.wav');
//  sample[3] = loadSound('./SS.wav');
//  sample[4] = loadSound('./CC.wav');
//  }

    function setup() {
        createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        background(0);
        fill(255);
        for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            bassDrum[i] = new drumButton(75 + i * 24, 50, bassRow, i);
            snareDrum[i] = new drumButton(75 + i * 24, 75, snareRow, i);
            hiHat[i] = new drumButton(75 + i * 24, 100, hiHatRow, i);
        }   
    }

    function draw() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            bassDrum[i].pressEvent();
            bassDrum[i].display();
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            snareDrum[i].pressEvent();
            snareDrum[i].display();
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            hiHat[i].pressEvent();
            hiHat[i].display();
        }
    }

class drumButton {
    
    constructor(x, y, steps, stepId) {
        this.x  = x;
        this.y = y;
        // this.w = w;
        // this.h = h;
        this.steps = steps;
        this.stepId = stepId;
    }
    
    display(){
        if (this.steps[this.stepId]){
            fill(255,col,col,100);
        } else {
            fill(255,255,255,100);
        }
        rect(this.x, this.y, 16, 16);
    }
    
    pressEvent(){
        if (this.steps[this.stepId] == false && mouseClicked && mouseX >= this.x && mouseX <= (this.x + this.w) && mouseY >= (this.y) && mouseY <= (this.y + this.h)){
            this.steps[this.stepId] = true;
        } else {
            this.steps[this.stepId] = false;
        }
    }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  if (col === 255) {
    col = 0;
  } else {
    col = 255;
  }
}

// function keyTyped(){
//  if (key == 'r') {
//      sample[0].play();
//  }
// }
```

`

I tried to make it so that when I clicked a square in the array that it would change colour while also changing its state (from false to true), but cannot get it to work.  I can change the colour without changing the state but not sure how to do it so that the colour changes and the state changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close just a couple things need tweaking. First of all you've got your `this.w` and `this.h` commented out, you need those for the click check.

I think it makes more sense for the `DrumButton` object to contain the state, so that it knows whether it's been clicked or not. This way you won't need to pass in the row *and* the index to the object. I've added an `active` state in the code below.

Also, take a look at the [mouseIsPressed system variable](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseIsPressed) -- this is more suited to your implementation.

```js
let sample = [];
let bassDrum = [];
let snareDrum = [];
let hiHat = [];

let bassRow = [16];
let snareRow = [16];
let hiHatRow = [16];

let col = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    bassDrum[i] = new DrumButton(75 + i * 24, 50, bassRow, i);
    snareDrum[i] = new DrumButton(75 + i * 24, 75, snareRow, i);
    hiHat[i] = new DrumButton(75 + i * 24, 100, hiHatRow, i);
  }
}

function draw() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    bassDrum[i].pressEvent();
    bassDrum[i].display();
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    snareDrum[i].pressEvent();
    snareDrum[i].display();
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    hiHat[i].pressEvent();
    hiHat[i].display();
  }
}

class DrumButton {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = 16;
    this.h = 16;
    this.active = false;
  }

  display() {
    if (this.active) {
      fill(255, col, col, 100);
    } else {
      fill(255, 255, 255, 100);
    }
    rect(this.x, this.y, 16, 16);
  }

  pressEvent() {
    if (
      mouseIsPressed &&
      mouseX >= this.x &&
      mouseX <= this.x + this.w &&
      mouseY >= this.y &&
      mouseY <= (this.y + this.h)
    ) {
      this.active = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Luke!  It was much, much simpler to do the active state than what I was doing!  Thank you for that quick help and support!

Comment: No worries! You can click the green tick to accept this answer if it's sorted it, gives me some reputation and a rush of endorphins 